# Is eating oranges at night bad for you?

Tags: medical-science, nutrition

I've always been told that eating oranges at night is bad for you.
In fact there is a saying that suggests that you might die if you eat them at night:
"Oranges in the morning are gold, afternoon silver and at night they kill!" (Translated from Portuguese where it rhymes so it sounds good)

Is there any truth to this saying and if not where could this myth come from?

Comment: The worst I've had happen to me is a case of 2AM diarrhea.  Diarrhea kills thousands of people every day.

Comment: What I've eared that It can cause damage, over a long term period, if you eat orange systematically with an "empty stomach". This is caused by the fact that this is quite acid. This advice will certainly be valid for lemon too, etc.

Comment: Do you have any idea whether acid should harm the stomach, sugar should kept you from sleeping (this would fit to bananas, apples and such as well) or maybe the acid harm your teeth?

Comment: I had 1/2 sour ornages an hour before going to bed, two times in this week. Both times, i did not have full sleep. It seemed that i had less urine both times. I am wondering, what could be the reason.

Comment: Maybe as an addition to this: I've heard that one shouldn't brush his teeth immediately after eating an orange, as the acid attacks the teeth, and rubbing a brush over them in this state does damage to them...?

Comment: In France & French-speaking Switzerland (at least), the belief is that vitamin C impairs sleep (much like caffeine), and thus people will generally refuse oranges, or orange juice, in the evening. (They also plant their seeds when there's a full moon... and firmly believe in homeopathy)

Comment: In Spanish the rhyme (as from my grand-mother) says "La naranja a la mañana es oro; a la tarde, plata, a la noche, plomo" ("Orange is gold at morning, silver at afternoon,  lead at night")

Comment: Very similar to the Portuguese: "Laranja de manhã é ouro, à tarde prata, à noite mata!"

Comment: Another sighting in [Italy](http://pamelaschoenewaldt.com/2011/05/13/not-to-do-in-italy/) - no rhyme though.

Comment: This question has been attracting more than its fair share of unreferenced answers. Please remember that our community standards require your claims to be cited.

Answer (score 4):

Recently, I came across some news that reminded me of this question I posed.

This news report is from a Portuguese TV channel and it does confirm that this saying is a myth, the origin of which seems to be rooted around the fact that in the past people used to steal oranges during the night. The saying was designed to discourage this.

[Comer laranja à noite não faz mal](http://www.rtp.pt/noticias/index.php?article=405638&tm=2&layout=122&visual=61)

The news report also mentions studies that have been made that confirm this as a myth although it doesn't say which studies specifically.
The dietitian on this report does mention that the orange can have a stimulant effect that could raise blood pressure slightly.

I have since found other posts that also confirm this saying as a myth:

- [Mitos e Crenças: A laranja de manhã é ouro, à tarde é prata e à
  noite mata!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1e9cvxZD58Y) - (Harvard Medical School-Portugal)
- [Comer laranja à noite faz mal?](http://mitos-alimentares.blogspot.com/2007/03/comer-laranja-noite-faz-mal.html)
- [Médico quebra mitos sobre a saúde](http://www.jn.pt/PaginaInicial/Sociedade/Saude/Interior.aspx?content_id=2451640&page=-1)